# how can i save this file using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

here is the error messages
raise

> ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

```
text = tweet.text #code to get my rawdata/tweets from twitter 
df = pd.DataFrame(text) 
df = ['created_at','tweet'] 
df.to_csv('tes1.csv')
df.head()
```

Comment: can you post the tweet.text sample and a sample expected dataframe as output?

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe constructor won't take strings. Convert it to a dict

```
import ast
dict = ast.literal_eval(string)
```